# Sync ES data/index between 2 machines?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

We have 2 machines running, prod and staging.  Both machines are identical.

We want to sync ES data/index van prod to staging so we can test also on staging with the most recent data set.  We use ES8 on both machines.

What is the best approach to sync ?

best remco

Comment: Definitely snapshots! You snapshot your prod data and restore it (or part thereof) on staging.

Comment: we make snapshots already per week for backup purpose.    I was searching for a realtime sync between 2 machines. Is there not a command todo this?  Elasticdump ?

Comment: Elasticdump is not real-time either, unless you run it on cron every "few minutes", but still not real-time... The true "real-time" feature is called [Cross cluster replication](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/xpack-ccr.html), but it's only available with a Platinum license.

Comment: Pay for cross cluster, as Val mentioned. Or do some homebrew with external tools (not worth it). Theoretically, you can even do it with Watchers (but that would be quite stupid, at my opinion). Or just ask yourself a question: what's the rush with testing that you need "realtime" there? What kind of "testing" is this?